# unique_ptr with array crash when calling reset

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Can someone explain the crash here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int *num1 = new int(5),  *num2 = new int(18);
    std::unique_ptr<int> numptr = std::unique_ptr<int>(num1);
    std::cout << *numptr.get() << '\n';  // 5
    numptr.reset(num2);
    std::cout << *numptr.get() << '\n';  // 18

    int a[5] = {0,2,4,6,8},  b[5] = {0,3,6,9,12};
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> u = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(a);
    std::cout << u[3] << '\n';  // 6
    u.reset(b);
    std::cout << u[3] << '\n';  // Crash.  Why???  Should output 9, right?
}
```

There is no crash when calling reset with `std::unique_ptr<int>`, so why the crash with `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`.  As I see it, `u` takes ownership of `b`, and then deletes `a`.  So `u[3]` should be `b[3] = 9` which should work fine because `b` is not deleted.  What's going on here?

Comment: `unique_ptr` can only manage dynamically allocated objects. Neither `a` nor  `b` are one of those.

Comment: Then what does `u` above do?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` assumes the dumb pointer it holds is allocated on the heap with `new` or `new[]`. In its destructor or `reset()`, it attempts to `delete` or `delete[]` said pointer. You instead are feeding it an address of an automatic object on the stack.

Comment: It causes *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrap your `unique_ptr` around an array, which has automatic storage duration and its memory will be released by the runtime. At the end of your program, `unique_ptr` tries to release the same memory. Basically the line `u.reset(b);` is equivalent to `delete[] a; // then set u to point to b`.

If you try a simple program like

```
int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    delete[] arr; // runtime error here
}
```

you'll get exactly the same error. You should never use smart pointers with non-dynamic objects.